# How to dynamically generate an intermediate class with Python 3 metaclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, metaclass

See full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/rossmacarthur/9b178e9a0b5450c652159ccea4f158ab)

Consider the case where we have a simple metaclass that generates the `__init__` method for a class

```
class TestType(type):

    def __new__(cls, cname, bases, attrs):
        # Dynamically create the __init__ function
        def init(self, message):
            self.message = message

        # Assign the created function as the __init__ method.
        attrs['__init__'] = init

        # Create the class.
        return super().__new__(cls, cname, bases, attrs)


class Test(metaclass=TestType):

    def get_message(self):
        return self.message
```

Now this is all good and well to use

```
test = Test('hello')
assert test.get_message() == 'hello'
```

But we have problems when subclassing, because if you want to subclass the `__init__` method what of course happens is the subclassed method just gets overwritten.

```
class SubTest(Test):

    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        super().__init__(first + ' ' second)

subtest = SubTest('hello', 'there')
```

This will obviously give the

```
TypeError: init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The only way I can think to solve this is to create an intermediate class in the `__new__` method of the metaclass and make this the base for the class we are creating. But I can't get this to work, I tried something like this

```
class TestType(type):

    def __new__(cls, cname, bases, attrs):
        # Dynamically create the __init__ function
        def init(self, message):
            self.message = message

        # If the __init__ method is being subclassed
        if '__init__' in attrs:
            # Store the subclass __init__
            sub_init = attrs.pop('__init__')

            # Assign the created function as the __init__ method.
            attrs['__init__'] = init

            # Create an intermediate class to become the base.
            interm_base = type(cname + 'Intermediate', bases, attrs)

            # Add the intermediate class as our base.
            bases = (interm_base,)

            # Assign the subclass __init__ as the __init__ method. 
            attrs['__init__'] = sub_init

        else:
            # Assign the created function as the __init__ method.
            attrs['__init__'] = init

        # Create the class.
        return super().__new__(cls, cname, bases, attrs)
```

But this gives me recursion error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that RecursionError.

Comment: Hmmm, thats weird, I get it on Python 3.7, Python 3.6, and Python 3.4 (Well python 3.4 is a RuntimeError). I am running macOS.

Comment: See full gist here https://gist.github.com/rossmacarthur/9b178e9a0b5450c652159ccea4f158ab

Comment: Oh, I'd accidentally overwritten the broken `TestType` class with the original `TestType` definition...

Comment: It's unclear to me what the expected behavior of your metaclass is when 1) the class already has an `__init__` method and 2) one of the class's parents is already an instance of `TestType`. Do you want to insert the default `init` *between* `SubTest.__init__` and `Test.__init__`?

Comment: Yes, I want to dynamically create `SubTestIntermediate` which is the new base for `SubTest`, and this class has the generated `__init__` method. `SubTestIntermediate` would have `Test` as its base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite recursion is caused by the fact that the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) constructor can return an instance of your metaclass.
In this line here:

```
interm_base = type(cname + 'Intermediate', bases, attrs)
```

If any of the base classes in `bases` is an instance of `TestType`, then the subclass will also be an instance of `TestType`. That is why `Test` can be created with no problems, but `SubTest` causes infinite recursion.

The fix is simple: Create the intermediate class *without* an `__init__` attribute. That way `if '__init__' in attrs:` will be `False`, and the endless recursion is avoided.

```
class TestType(type):
    def __new__(cls, cname, bases, attrs):
        # Dynamically create the __init__ function
        def init(self, message):
            self.message = message

        # If the __init__ method is being subclassed
        if '__init__' in attrs:
            # Create an intermediate class to become the base.
            interm_base = type(cname + 'Intermediate', bases, {})

            # Add the intermediate class as our base.
            bases = (interm_base,)
        else:
            # Assign the created function as the __init__ method.
            attrs['__init__'] = init

        # Create the class.
        return super().__new__(cls, cname, bases, attrs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that the `__new__` would be called multiple times when we subclass.